# create a user with hashed password

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've problems with laravel i need to do an application and need put the password hashed.

My view code is:

```
{{ Form::open(array('route' => 'users.store')) }}
<li>
   {{ Form::label('password', 'Confirmar Password:') }}
   {{ Form::password('password_confirmation') }}
</li>
{{Form::close()}}
```

My Controller is:

```
public function store()
    {
        $input = Input::all();
        $validation = Validator::make($input, User::$rules);

        if ($validation->passes())
        {
            User::create($input);

            return Redirect::route('users.index');
        }

        return Redirect::route('users.create')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validation)
            ->with('message', 'Existem erros de validação.');
    }
```

I need to save the user password hashed in database can you help me, please? Thank you, so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest that you add each item in the array yourself...

```
User::create(array(
    'username' => Input::get('username'),
    'password' => Hash::make(Input::get('password'))
));
```

Additionally, you can create a mutator in your user model which will set it for you.  This method is easier but not as safe in the case that eventually you start saving a hashed password like above.  If that were to happen, you'd start seeing double hashed passwords.

```
public function setPasswordAttribute($password)
{
    $this->attributes['password'] = Hash::make($password);
}
```

Comment: setting `setPasswordAttribute` is not correct way
Since if you are trying to edit the password it will re hash the password. So after edit data your password wouldn't work.